# Calling a Method From Another Activity

Tags: android, class, methods, getter-setter

Well, I tried the classic method call strategies but wasn't able to succeed. What I want is to call getDayOfTheWeek() and other get methods from Daily to Receive.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String DAILY_FORECAST = "DAILY_FORECAST";
public static final String HOURLY_FORECAST = "HOURLY_FORECAST";
private Forecast mForecast;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
boolean isNotificActive = false;
int notifID = 33;

@Bind(R.id.timeLabel)
TextView mTimeLabel;
@Bind(R.id.tempLabel)
TextView mTempLabel;
@Bind(R.id.humidityValue)
TextView mHumidityValue;
@Bind(R.id.precipValue)
TextView mPrecipValue;
@Bind(R.id.summaryLabel)
TextView mSummaryLabel;
@Bind(R.id.windSpeedValue)
TextView mWindSpeedValue;
@Bind(R.id.relativeLayout)
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
@Bind(R.id.container)
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
@Bind(R.id.locationLabel)
TextView mLocationLabel;
@Bind(R.id.notifButton)
ImageButton mNotifButton;

double latitude;
double longitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    final GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 1750);
            gpsTracker.getLocation();
            double x = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
            double y = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
            if (x == 0.00 || y == 0.00) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                getForecast(gpsTracker);
            }
        }
    });
    double x = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    double y = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    if (x == 0.00 || y == 0.00) {
        gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
    } else {
        getForecast(gpsTracker);
    }
    setAlarm(calendar);
}

public void showNotification(View view) {

    Currently currently = mForecast.getCurrently();
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Weather")
            .setContentText(currently.getSummary() + " and Temperature: " + currently.getTemperature())
            .setTicker("Current Weather")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clear_nighticon);

    Intent moreInfoIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(moreInfoIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(notifID, notificBuilder.build());

    isNotificActive = true;
}

public void stopNotification(View view) {

    if(isNotificActive) {
        notificationManager.cancel(notifID);
    }
}

public void setAlarm(Calendar calendar) {


    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alertIntent, 0);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 26);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    gpsTracker.getLocation();
    double x = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    double y = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    if (x == 0.00 || y == 0.00) {

    } else {
        getForecast(gpsTracker);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

public void getForecast(final GPSTracker gpsTracker) {

    latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    String apiKey = "7d22cdb138cd70f2e9e8d2006cd0461c";
    String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey
            + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(forecastUrl).build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                alertUserAboutError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateDisplay(gpsTracker);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                } catch (IOException |
                        JSONException e
                        )

                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert2();
    }
}

private void updateDisplay(GPSTracker gpsTracker) {

    Currently currently = mForecast.getCurrently();

    String area = gpsTracker.getSubLocality(this);
    String city = gpsTracker.getAdminArea(this);
    String country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);
    mLocationLabel.setText(area + "\n" + city + ", " + country);
    mTempLabel.setText(currently.getTemperature() + "");
    mTimeLabel.setText(currently.getFormattedTime());
    mHumidityValue.setText((int) (currently.getHumidity()) + "%");
    mPrecipValue.setText((int) (currently.getPrecipChance()) + "%");
    mSummaryLabel.setText(currently.getSummary());
    mWindSpeedValue.setText((int) (currently.getWindSpeed()) + "");
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(currently.getBackgroundId());
    mRelativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
}

private Forecast parseForecastDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    Forecast forecast = new Forecast();

    forecast.setCurrently(getCurrentlyDetails(jsonData));
    forecast.setHourlyForecast(getHourlyForecast(jsonData));
    forecast.setDailyForecast(getDailyForecast(jsonData));

    return forecast;
}

private Daily[] getDailyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    JSONObject jsonDaily = forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
    JSONArray data = jsonDaily.getJSONArray("data");

    Daily[] days = new Daily[data.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject daily = data.getJSONObject(i);
        Daily day = new Daily();

        day.setSummary(daily.getString("summary"));
        day.setTempMax(daily.getDouble("temperatureMax"));
        day.setTempMin(daily.getDouble("temperatureMin"));
        day.setIcon(daily.getString("icon"));
        day.setTime(daily.getLong("time"));
        day.setTimezone(timezone);

        days[i] = day;
    }
    return days;
}

private Hourly[] getHourlyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    JSONObject jsonHourly = forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
    JSONArray data = jsonHourly.getJSONArray("data");

    Hourly[] hours = new Hourly[data.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject hourly = data.getJSONObject(i);
        Hourly hour = new Hourly();

        hour.setSummary(hourly.getString("summary"));
        hour.setTemp(hourly.getDouble("temperature"));
        hour.setIcon(hourly.getString("icon"));
        hour.setTime(hourly.getLong("time"));
        hour.setHumidity(hourly.getDouble("humidity"));
        hour.setWindSpeed(hourly.getDouble("windSpeed"));
        hour.setTimezone(timezone);

        hours[i] = hour;
    }
    return hours;
}

private Currently getCurrentlyDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");

    Currently currentWeather = new Currently();
    currentWeather.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
    currentWeather.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
    currentWeather.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
    currentWeather.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
    currentWeather.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
    currentWeather.setWindSpeed(currently.getDouble("windSpeed"));
    currentWeather.setTimeZone(timezone);
    currentWeather.setBackgroundId(currently.getString("icon"));

    Log.d(TAG, currentWeather.getFormattedTime());

    return currentWeather;
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}

private void alertUserAboutError() {
    AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
}

@OnClick(R.id.dailyButton)
public void startDailyActivity(View view) {
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    double x = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    double y = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        if (x == 0.00 || y == 0.00) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enable Location services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyForecastActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DAILY_FORECAST, mForecast.getDailyForecast());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable Network services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.hourlyButton)
public void startHourlyActivity(View view) {
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    double x = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    double y = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        if (x == 0.00 || y == 0.00) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enable Location services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HourlyForecastActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(HOURLY_FORECAST, mForecast.getHourlyForecast());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable Network services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

**Daily.java:**

```
public class Daily implements Parcelable{

private long mTime;
private String mSummary;
private double mTempMax;
private String mIcon;
private String mTimezone;
private double mTempMin;

public String getDayOfTheWeek() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(mTimezone));
    Date dateTime = new Date(mTime * 1000);
    return formatter.format(dateTime);
}

public double getTempMin() {
    double celciusTemp = 100 * (mTempMin - 32) / 180;
    return (int)Math.round(celciusTemp);
}

public void setTempMin(double tempMin) {
    mTempMin = tempMin;
}

public long getTime() {
    return mTime;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    mTime = time;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return mSummary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    mSummary = summary;
}

public double getTempMax() {
    double celciusTemp = 100 * (mTempMax - 32) / 180;
    return (int)Math.round(celciusTemp);
}

public void setTempMax(double tempMax) {
    mTempMax = tempMax;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return mIcon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    mIcon = icon;
}

public String getTimezone() {
    return mTimezone;
}

public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
    mTimezone = timezone;
}

public int getIconId(){
    return Forecast.getIconId(mIcon);
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(mTime);
    dest.writeString(mSummary);
    dest.writeDouble(mTempMax);
    dest.writeDouble(mTempMin);
    dest.writeString(mIcon);
    dest.writeString(mTimezone);
}

private Daily(Parcel in){
    mTime = in.readLong();
    mSummary = in.readString();
    mTempMax = in.readDouble();
    mTempMin = in.readDouble();
    mIcon = in.readString();
    mTimezone = in.readString();
}

public Daily(){

}

public static final Creator<Daily> CREATOR = new Creator<Daily>() {
    @Override
    public Daily createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Daily(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Daily[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Daily[size];
    }
};
}
```

**Receive.java:**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Daily day = new Daily();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    createNotification(context,
            day.getDayOfTheWeek(),
            day.getSummary() + " and Max: " + day.getTempMax() + " Min: " + day.getTempMin(),
            "Your Daily Weather");

    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg,
                                  String msgText, String msgAlert) {
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(day.getIconId())
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText(msgText)
            .setTicker(msgAlert);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
            mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

See, the problem is even though this is correct way to call in many cases, this one fails. I have no idea what the problem is, I declared a Daily variable, used it to call the methods, those getBLA() methods return String so it's okay too...
Note that other get methods also exist in Daily.java, but I just wanted to focus on one of them. None of them work. Would really appreciate any help. Also if there are no errors in these codes, I can provide the whole thing. Just let me know please.

**DayAdapter.java**

```
public class DayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private Daily[] mDays;

public DayAdapter(Context context, Daily[] days){
    mContext = context;
    mDays = days;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDays.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDays[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null){
        // brand new
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.daily_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
        holder.tempLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tempLabel);
        holder.dayLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayNameLabel);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Daily day = mDays[position];

    holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(day.getIconId());
    holder.tempLabel.setText(((int)day.getTempMax()) + "/" + ((int)day.getTempMin()));

    if (position == 0){
        holder.dayLabel.setText("Today");
    } else {
        holder.dayLabel.setText(day.getDayOfTheWeek());
    }
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView iconImageView;
    TextView tempLabel;
    TextView dayLabel;
}
}
```

**DailyForecastActivity.java**

```
public class DailyForecastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Daily[] mDays;

String dayoftheweek;
@Bind(android.R.id.list)
ListView mListView;
@Bind(android.R.id.empty)
TextView mEmptyTextView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_forecast);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    TextView mLocationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationLabel);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.DAILY_FORECAST);
        mDays = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Daily[].class);
        DayAdapter adapter = new DayAdapter(this, mDays);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyTextView);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String dayOfTheWeek = mDays[position].getDayOfTheWeek();
                String condition = mDays[position].getSummary();

                if (mDays[position].getSummary().contains("Mixed")) {
                    condition = "There will be Mixed Precipitation";
                }
                if (mDays[position].getSummary().contains("Snow")) {
                    condition = "There will be Snow";
                }
                if (mDays[position].getSummary().contains("Partly cloudy")) {
                    condition = "It will be Partly Cloudy";
                }
                if (mDays[position].getSummary().contains("Light rain")) {
                    condition = "There will be Light Rain";
                }
                if (mDays[position].getSummary().contains("Rain")) {
                    condition = "There will be Rain";
                }
                String message = String.format("%s Summary: %s", dayOfTheWeek, condition);
                Toast.makeText(DailyForecastActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        String area = gpsTracker.getSubLocality(this);
        String city = gpsTracker.getAdminArea(this);
        String country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);
        mLocationLabel.setText(area + ", " + city + ", " + country);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "this one fails" means and what "None of them work" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I meant "none of the other methods work". I asked for the solution to getDayOfTheWeek() method, so that I could apply that to others also. And by "this one fails", I meant this is the usual way I call methods from other classes, but this time it did not work.

Comment: post the **// notification stuff** also

Comment: @Virus I edited the original question with // notification stuff

Comment: put a breakpoint inside createNotification and see if you are getting the value there. Then it is a problem with your notification method otherwise we will look into the class.

Comment: "but this time it did not work" -- you still have not explained what "did not work" means. Are you having compile problems? Are you crashing at runtime (and, if so, what does your Java stack trace tell you)? To draw an analogy, saying "it did not work" is like going to your doctor, saying "I do not feel well", and not explaining anything more about your symptoms. As it stands, it is unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: @Virus Well, it's a timed auto notification. How do I debug that? When I put a breakpoint in it and start debug, it directs me to setAlarm() method in MainActivity.

Comment: oh yes! try printing Logs and see if you get the values right?

Comment: btw, do you see the notification? or dont see it at all. and if you see, do the values show there?

Comment: @Virus Okay I did my best on debug as a newbie, and what I've seen so far is that I'm getting "null" value for msg, which is represented by day.getDayOfTheWeek(). So I guess I'm not getting that value at all. And I'm not getting any notification. I set the time and app crashes when the time comes. Also I'm getting a NullPointerException error followed by id == null, pointing me that day.getDayOfTheWeek() method in Receive.java

Comment: Right, that gives us a direction. Now share your full classes. Let me have a look.

Comment: @Virus I provided other classes and activities that have anything to do with that Daily data. Edit: I also edited the whole Daily.java

Comment: don't need everything but its allright. Daily class is still part pasted i guess

Comment: @Virus That showNotification() and stopNotification() methods in MainActivity are not related to the main notification stuff by the way, they are seperate and working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Daily` class, you've declared the variables

```
private long mTime;
private String mSummary;
private double mTempMax;
private String mIcon;
private String mTimezone;
private double mTempMin;
```

I see that you create a new instance of `Daily` in your `createNotification` method and start calling the get methods.

But, where are the values set for all those declared variables? They are still `null` when you call the get methods for each in the `createNotification` method.

Are you missing a method call in between to set these values? You should probably create a constructor in the `Daily` class which sets the values for all these variables before you start getting them?

**How to write the constructor:**

```
public class Daily implements Parcelable{

private long mTime;
private String mSummary;
private double mTempMax;
private String mIcon;
private String mTimezone;
private double mTempMin;

//constructor
public Daily(long mTime, String mSummary, double mTempMax, String mIcon, String mTimezone, double mTempMin) {
     this.mTime =  mTime;
     this.mSummary = mSummary;
     this.mtempMax = mTempMax;
     ...
     ...
     ...

}

// rest of your code below this as it is
```

And now **create your instance for Daily Class like this**:

```
Daily day = new Daily(3131313, "Summary",  107, "icon", "timezone", 91);
// replace these hardcoded values with sensible values from your data source
```

*Alternatively create a constructor with no arguments and get the values to initialize the variables directly in your constructor. However it works for you.*

After this your code should work fine.

Comment: I originally use those Daily getter-setters in a list view in DayAdapter to show in DailyForecastActivity layout. I'm trying to pull datas from that Daily methods and show them in my notification.

Comment: Yes, but they way your code is at the moment will only keep them null. You need to put something in between creating an instance of the `Daily` class and calling its get methods which would initialize the variables with some values. Else you'll just keep getting null.

Comment: @OnurÇevik in your `createNotification()`, you created a new `Daily` object. Usually when you construct a new object, you pass parameters to initialize the object. Since your `Daily` constructor is empty, all the members of `Daily` are null, regardless if you have set them in another instance somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Virus Okay, I get what you say. I thought of that too, but couldn't apply. I tried something like String dayofthewekk = day.getDayOfTheWeek(); and it didn't solve it. Can you give me an example on how to initialize it?

Comment: @ChrisTarazi yes, that's what the answer concludes with.

Comment: @Chris Hi Chris, yeah I figured the problem also. I'm getting your point, yet I have no clue on what to do to solve this.

Comment: @OnurÇevik I'm adding a basic constructor with hard coded values. Its up to you the how/where you get those values from. Check updated answer in a moment.

Comment: did a small correction if you already checked before this comment

Comment: @Virus  Okay, but I'm not getting a hard-coded value for String mSummary, so what should I right inside of Daily day = new Daily(here) object for summary? I'm getting a JSON data for it.

Comment: thats what i edited before a while. it was a pasting mistake earlier. So, there you parse your json and assign the fields their respective values. in that case you could use a constructor without parameters. and declare the instance like you were doing before (i.e. if you get the json inside the constructor)

Comment: @Virus Yeah, that's kind of messed up. So you are telling me to parse the json data I'm getting in MainActivity to Daily's Daily() constructor? Well, it will still be a dynamic value I'm getting from api, so again how would I call that JSON data?

Comment: you could do the parsing where ever you deem fit. The issue is that before calling the get methods, the data should reach the Daily Class members else you will continue to get null. :) That was your main issue.

Comment: @Virus thanks for the help. Looks like I went a little over my head on this one. I'll read some docs before proceeding.

Comment: @Virus sorry to bother you once again, but I've been trying things since then and haven't figured out anything. Using constructors, like I said doesn't let me get the dynamic data. There is only one solution that comes to my mind, which is to get the whole JSON data again in that Receiver.java, detect the location once again etc. which is kind of a brute solution to it. Do you possibly have any more advice on this situation? Here is a screenshot from my app which shows an item of list view. All I want is to get those dynamic info and put them in a notification. http://prntscr.com/9mza0f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100015/discussion-between-virus-and-onur-cevik).